# UI text display in World Space

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, oculus

I have added to my scene a simple `text` element on a `Canvas` that is set to `World Space`, so I can see it in VR, but no matter how much I change the size or how far away or close I get it to the camera, etc... it still shows a very blurry kind of text (which I use to display time).

The situation can be seen in the attached image, as well as my `Canvas` settings in the other image. Could someone please help me understand which setting(s) I should deal with to get this sorted?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, can you also show the properties for your parent `Canvas` element? They could shed a bit more light on the situation.

Comment: Absolutely... I will add an EDIT to show that.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the Canvas Scaler is the source of the problem here. For a Canvas set to the world space, the Canvas Scaler controls the [pixel density of UI element in the Canvas](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html).

To increase the pixel density (which should make rendered text sharper), you can raise the value of `Dynamic Pixels Per Unit`, which should increase the number of pixels used per unit to render your Text. I don't have an exact value for you, as this may vary based on circumstance; you'll just have to experiment to see what value works best for you.

An alternative workaround is to scale the Text way, way down, but increase its `Font Size` property proportionally.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you Serlite. You were absolutely right. Raising the value of `Dynamic Pixels Per Unit` resolved my problem.